# Get nested/hierarchical JSON from MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, hierarchical-data

I am using [spacetree chart](http://thejit.org/tutorials/spacetree/) and I require JSON in hierarchical format. See sample required JSON format [here](http://thejit.org/tutorials/spacetree/). I have ID,ParentID,Name,Description fields in Mysql database table. Now How can I convert data in Hierarchical/nested JSON using PHP? 
I know json_encode($array). But, I require nested/Hierarchical php array for this.
Let me know to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically asking two questions here - 1) how to get an hierarchical php structure from a db table and 2) how to encode this structure in json. For the first question see, for example, my (old but working) [code](http://stereofrog.com/blok/on/061029). For the second, I believe simple json_encode will work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks @stereofrog. You are very close to my object.the encoded format is different from required json. I don't require parent_ID and some additional stuff are coming.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP json extension on your server installed, just use it on an array. The steps will be:

1. Build PHP array with hierarchy based on mysql resutls
2. call a json_encode($array) http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

If you don't have json_encode enabled on your server and cannot install it... You'll just have to write it by hand.

It'll be something like that **(untested code warning)**:

```
function my_json_encode($array)
{
  $return = '{';
  $count = count($array);
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($array as $key => $val)
  {
    $return .= '"'.$key.'" : ';
    if (!is_array($val))
      $return .= '"'.$val.'"';
    else
      $return .= my_json_encode($val);
    if ($i < $count-1)
      $return .=",";
    $i++;
  }
  $return .= '}';
  return $return;
}
```

Comment: This solution is a simple proof-of-concept and has to be enhanced. To add is, for example, object type support and some error handle. It's better to use json_encode anyway.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. If you're sending json, remember that you should set appropriate headers in response. Like: header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: Now my question is how to create nested/hierarchical php array?